# Finding Common Sets within noisy data

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Context: Consider each set within `G` to be a collection of the files (contents or MD5 hashes, not names) that are found on a particular computer.

Suppose I have a giant list of giant sets `G` and an unknown to me list of sets `H`.  Each individual set `I` in `G` was created by taking the union of some unknown number of sets from list `H`, then adding and removing an unknown number of elements.

Now, I could use other data to construct a few of the sets in list `H`.  However, I feel like there might be some sort of technique involving [Bayesian probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_probability) to do this.  E.g. something like, "If finding `X` in a set within `G` means there is a high probability of also finding `Y`, then there is probably a set in `H` containing both `X` and `Y`."

Edit: My goal is to construct a set of sets that is, with high probability, very similar or equal to `H`.

Any thoughts?

Example usage:

Compress `G` by replacing chunks of it with pieces of `H`, e.g.

```
G[1]  = {1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10,11}
H[5]  = {1,2,3}
H[6]  = {5,6,7,8,9,10}
G[1]' = {H[5],H[6],-8,11}
```

Comment: So the input is this "giant list of giant sets `G`". What's the output you're trying to compute?

Comment: @Laurence: The output is `H`...or at least, something that is, with high probability, very similar to `H`.  I'll edit to make this more clear.

Comment: @moonshadow: I don't think the image set sharing example is that relevant, since I can at will take the intersection of a pair of sets from `G`

Comment: Does http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem help at all?

Comment: You want the cardinality of G[1]' to be as small as possible, right?

Comment: @Ipthnc: I want the cardinality of G[1]' to be small, but absolutely minimizing it is not necessary.  And my problem is similar set cover, since I want to cover the sets I have, not use them to cover everything.  I feel like set cover is working in the wrong direction, sort of.

Comment: So ... is the nature of this problem compression? Something else? Are you pushing the theory forward or trying to solve a particular applied problem? Sorry if this sounds biased.

Comment: I'm just looking into more effective ways to represent some data.  More to improve speed (by shrinking the size of the data during reads and writes) than because I am concerned about the size itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the distance d(i,j) = 1/(number of sets in G which contain both i and j) and then run a cluster analysis.(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) The resulting clusters are your candidates for the elements in H.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the correct place to look for info on this kind of problem.

Comment: I don't think that's quite how you want to define distance, but the link alone is worth an upvote.

Comment: The reason I think d(i, j)=1/(number of sets in G which contain both i and j) isn't the right distance function is that it's very small when i and j are both very common but not at all correlated, and much larger when i and j are both rare but highly correlated.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of non-brainy *ad hoc* ways to attack this. Here's one.

Start by taking a random sample from G, say 64 sets.

For each file in these sets, construct a 64-bit integer telling which sets it appears in.

Group the files by this 64-bit value; so all the files that always appear together end up in the same group. Find the group with maximum ((number of files in group - 1) × (number of bits set in the bit-vector - 1)) and call that H[0].

Now throw that sample back and take a new random sample. Reduce it as much as you can using the H[0] you've already defined. Then apply the same algorithm to find H[1]. Rinse. Repeat.

Stop when additional H's are no longer helping you compress the sets.

To improve on this algorithm:

- You can easily choose a slightly different measure of the goodness of groups that promotes groups with lots of nearby neighbors--files that appear in *nearly* the same set of sets.
- You can also pretty easily test your existing H's against random samples from G to see if there are files you should consider adding or removing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the current ad-hoc way, which seems to be good enough, is as follows:

- Remove all elements from all `G_x` that are in under 25 sets.
- Create a mapping from element to set and from set to element.
- For each element `E` in the element map, pick 3 sets and take their intersection.  Make two copies of this, `A` and `B`.
- For each set `S` in the set map that does not contain `E`, remove all elements of `S` from `A` or `B` (alternate between them)
- Add `Union(A,B)` to `H`
- Remove all elements of `Union(A,B) from the element to set map (i.e. do not find overlapping sets).

Answer (score 0):

How about a deterministic way (if you do not wish sets to intersect at all):
A) Turn sets in H into vertices labeled 1, 2, 3, ... size(H). Create a complete [un] directed graph between them all. Each vertex gets a value - equal to the cardinality / size of the set.
B) Go through all elements x in sets in H, create a mapping x -> [x1, x2, ... xm] if and only if x is in H[xi]. An array of sets will do. This helps you find overlapping sets.
C) Go through through all sets in this array, for every pair of x1, x2 that are within the same set - eliminate two edges between x1 and x2.
D) In the remaining graph only non-overlapping sets (well, their indices in H).
E) Now find the non-intersecting path within this graph with the highest total value. From this you can reconstruct the list of non-intersecting sets with highest coverage. It is trivial to compute the missing elements.
F) If you want to minimize the cardinality of the remaining set, then subtract 0.5 from the value of each vertex. We know that 1 + 1 = 2, but 0.5 + 0.5 < 1.5 - so the algorithm will prefer a set {a,b} over {a} and {b}. This may not be exactly what you want, but it might expire you.

Comment: Hm ... please enlighten me on G with examples. How do you supposedly construct G[2]? Thanks.